# Get commits from a specific branch in github

Tags: python, github

Want to get the commits from a different branch rather than the master branch. It lists the commits from the master branch.I have 2 branch in my Repo master and test, i want the commit from the test branch instead of master.

I have already tried the below to get the list from the github repo but it gives the commits for master branch

```
github_commits = repo.get_commits()
```

full code that i have tried:

```
from github import Github  

g = Github(base_url="https://my_hostnaame/api/v3", 
login_or_token="my_access_token") 
org = g.get_organization("my_org") 
repo = org.get_repo("my_repo_name") 
github_commits = repo.get_commits()
print(github_commits)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do the following:

```
branch = g.get_repo("my_repo_name").get_branch("master")
print(branch.commit)
```

I assumed you installed `PyGithub`

[here is the full usage of branch method](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Branch.html)

Comment: i have installed PyGithub

Comment: same we can use for organization as well?

Comment: iam using Github Enterprise and want to do for repos under organizations